# Get paths to Unity source files

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to look at the source files in a Unity project, and I am wondering if it is possible to get paths to all the scripts in the Assets folder that will be incorporated into the built player. I know I can get all the C# scripts in the Assets folder like so:

```cs
var scripts = AssetDatabase.FindAssets(string.Empty, new[] { "Assets" })
    .Select(guid => AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid))
    .Where(path => path.EndsWith(".cs"));
```

But is it possible to get a collection containing all the scripts in the Assets folder that will end up being compiled into the player, i.e. non-editor scripts?

Comment: [This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/975394/cleaning-project-of-unused-scripts.html) might help.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres probably not ... this doesn't work for seeing if a script is actually "needed" in order to successfully build and run an app ... OP seems to be asking which scripts could be deleted with the app still compiling, building and running normal.

Comment: As I know when you build your project, there is a list in the editor.log, is it help? Can you tell us what's the purpose of collecting the scripts? There may be a workaround.

Comment: @derHugo in that link [one of the comments](http://answers.unity.com/comments/1313416/view.html) says `Sadly, there is no magic automated way of knowing which scripts are being used.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Unity provides readily accessible information about source files that will be compiled into the built player via their own assembly system. You can get the paths to these files like so:

```cs
var assemblies = CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies(AssembliesType.Player);
var sourcefiles = assemblies
    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.sourceFiles)
    .Where(file => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) && file.StartsWith("Assets"));
```

`CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies(AssembliesType.Player)` will retrieve a collection of Unity `Assembly` objects for each of the assemblies that will be built into the player. Each of these contains an array of file paths of the source files that constitute it through the `Assembly.sourceFiles` property. This will find all of the project scripts and scripts in any installed packages, as well as scripts in any custom assembly definitions that have been created, so filtering by `file.StartsWith("Assets")` will retrieve only the scripts inside the Assets folder.

This will cull off any scripts inside any `Editor` folders, as well as any scripts inside assembly definitions that are editor-only, which is exactly what I needed. It will *still*, however, retrieve scripts that may be present in runtime assemblies but are not actually used in the project (i.e. a Monobehaviour that isn't used in any scenes, or a script bounded by `#if UNITY_EDITOR` directives) To exclude such scripts is an entirely different matter and there is no easy way to do such a thing that I know of.